# Building a dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

Suppose I have a 4 dimensional system with 4 fixed points: $Q_1 = \left(p_1,0,0,0 \right)$, $Q_2 = \left(0,p_2,0,0 \right)$, $Q_3= \left(0,0,p_3,0 \right)$, and $Q_4 = \left(0,0,0,p_4 \right)$. Furthermore, I'd like there to be separatrices connecting them in this fashion:

$$Q_1 \rightarrow Q_2 \rightarrow Q_3 \rightarrow Q_1$$ and $$Q_1 \rightarrow Q_2 \rightarrow Q_4 \rightarrow Q_1$$

Essentially, it looks something like this:

[image]

I've seen this design used in a number of papers but not one of them has produced an explicit example of a dynamical system which has this behavior. I can easily find a dynamical system where each cycle exists separately, but not one where the 2 cycles share a joint edge (e.g. Competitive Lotka-Volterra equations, Guckenheimer-Holmes cycle, etc). Is it possible to come up with such a system that has this behavior?

Comment: I'm freaking amazed that someone else asks here about heteroclinic cycles. Speaking about your question, I think that you've missed this paper: V. Kirk, M. Silber, *"A competition between heteroclinic cycles"*.

Comment: @Evgeny Haha I'm guessing you've asked before? Thank you for the paper. I remember coming across that one the other day but I don't recall seeing in there that they gave an explicit ODE system that gave rise to this design. I'll have to check again later today when I can access the paper today

Comment: Well, I'm usually studying this topic "in silence" and ask here only byproducts of this interest :) As far as I remember Kirk and Silber had somewhat explicit formulas for their example. At least the latest P. Ashwin paper covers how to construct Kirk-Silber network explicitly (I mean P.Ashwin, C.Postlethwaite, *"Designing heteroclinic and excitable networks in phase space using two populations of coupled cells"*; you can find it on arXiv).

Comment: @Evgeny Ah yes, I also have this paper. I tried plotting it (without the $y_i$ terms) since I just want the cycle, but it seems not to be working? Namely I'm plotting:

$$\frac{dp_1}{dt} = p_1(F(1-p^2)+D(p_1^2p^2-p^4)$$

and similarly for $p_2$ and $p_3$ from equation 2. I see they give explicit equations with both $p$ and $y$ but I wanted one without $y$ too if possible

Comment: Ah, so you want 4D model? I've taken a look at Kirk&Silber article, they don't have an explicit formula, but they left the clue. I take a quote from them: "We note that this symmetry group can be introduced, through a simple coordinate transformation, to differential equations that
model population dynamics and have the form $p_j = p_jg_j(p)$, $j = 1,2,3,4$, where
$p = (p_1 ,p_2, p_3, p_4)$ .... . Specifically, let $p_j = x^2$, where $p_j > 0$. In this way, our example may be viewed as a four-dimensional generalization of the threedimensional competitive species model of May and Leonard"

Comment: @Evgeny I Think the 4D model is necessary in order to have two competing heteroclinic cycles, each with 3 axial fixed points. The May and Leonard model is basically:

$$\frac{dN_1}{dt} = N_1\left(1 - N_1 - \alpha N_2 - \beta N_3 \right)$$

and so forth. So in their case, it looks like $\frac{d(x_1^2)}{dt} = x_1^2g_j(x^2)$... something seems off

Comment: As I've understood, their point is that it's possible to find example in form $\frac{dx_1}{dt} = x_1 (1 - x_1^2 - \alpha x^2_2 - \beta x_3^2 - \gamma x_4^2)$ and so on. I'll try to take a look at these systems if I won't be out of time.

Comment: @Evgeny Ah yes, ok that makes more sense than what I wrote. Thank you. I'd appreciate any and all help I can get!